# "If I asked, would she say it were/was time?" Past Vs. Subjunctive

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, subjunctive-mood

Is there any reason to use the subjunctive mood in the question "If I asked, would she say it were/was time?" There's an air of uncertainty about "were" when compared to the past tense "was," but is it grammatical to use the subjunctive? Archaic?

Comment: Turn the question into a sentence, "If I asked, she would say it was time." So the correct verb is "was." "If I asked, would she say it was time?

Comment: @ArchDenton In what way does that address the question about possible use of the subjunctive?

Comment: She would say if it were time, if I asked, wouldn't she?

Comment: Short simple answer: you probably don't need the subjunctive for your sentence.

Comment: @Helmar She would so say, if it was, as it were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fowler says the past simple is used in clauses that depend on a clause in the past subjunctive, so it should be *was*. I and almost everyone, I believe, will agree with this advice. There is no specific reason why this is so: in fact, the past subjunctive is possible or even compulsory there in other languages, or even in older English. I don't have the quotation on hand at the moment, but I'll try to find it.

Answer (score 1):

No, in fact the subjunctive "were" is not possible here.  I don't know why.  I can't think of an example in modern English where subjunctive "were" can be used in the "then" clause of an if-then construction.  But in older English, we have Macbeth saying "If it were done when 'tis done, then 'twere well it were done quickly."

Answer (score 0):

> "If I asked, would she say it were/was time?"

9h. The subjunctive *were* is used in contrary-to-fact statements (after *if* or *as* *though*) and in statements expressing a wish.--Warriner's.

To create the subjunctive mood, you would have to change your sentence to: "If I were to ask, would she say it was time?"

John E. Warriner. Warriner’s English Grammar and Composition. Fifth Course. Liberty Edition. Orlando, Florida: Harcourt, Brace, and Jovanovich. 1986. 208.